# In CosmicMind / Material SnackbarController, how do I start (show) the snackbar?

Tags: ios, swift3, edit, cosmicmind

In CosmicMind / Material library, how do I start (show) the snackbar?

I have tried to prepare the snackbarController and then show it whenever the user clicks on a button.

As shown in their example:

```
private var undoButton: FlatButton!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    prepareSnackbar()
    animateSnackbar()
}

@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sc?.show(vc: UIViewControlle, sender: Any)//doesn't show
    more code... (which works)
}
private func prepareUndoButton() {
    undoButton = FlatButton(title: "Undo", titleColor: Color.yellow.base)
    undoButton.pulseAnimation = .backing
    undoButton.titleLabel?.font = RobotoFont.regular(with: 14)
}

private func prepareSnackbar() {
    guard let sc = snackbarController else {
        return
    }
    sc.snackbar.text = "Reminder saved."
    sc.snackbar.rightViews = [undoButton]

}

private func animateSnackbar() {
    guard let sc = snackbarController else {
        return
    }
    _ = sc.animate(snackbar: .visible, delay: 1)
    _ = sc.animate(snackbar: .hidden, delay: 4)
}
```

So I did try it on an empty project and the snackbar still doesn't work. Could you please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit
 import Material

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

private var undoButton: FlatButton!


open override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = Color.red.accent1

    prepareUndoButton()
}

open override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //prepareSnackbar()
    //animateSnackbar()
}

private func prepareUndoButton() {
    undoButton = FlatButton(title: "Undo", titleColor: Color.yellow.base)
    undoButton.pulseAnimation = .backing
    undoButton.titleLabel?.font = RobotoFont.regular(with: 14)
}

private func prepareSnackbar() {
    guard let sc = snackbarController else {
        return
    }

    sc.snackbar.text = "Reminder saved."
    sc.snackbar.rightViews = [undoButton]
}

private func animateSnackbar() {
    guard let sc = snackbarController else {
        return
    }

    _ = sc.animate(snackbar: .visible, delay: 1)
    _ = sc.animate(snackbar: .hidden, delay: 4)
}


@IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("TEST TEST TEST")

    prepareSnackbar()
    animateSnackbar()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice in the `viewDidAppear` function you have an `animateSnackbar` call, which calls the lines

```
_ = sc.animate(snackbar: .visible, delay: 1)
_ = sc.animate(snackbar: .hidden, delay: 4)
```

You can basically use the `animateSnackbar` function in your button handler, like so:

```
@IBAction func loginBtnTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    animateSnackbar()
}
```

That's it. There are two animations playing, one to show and one to hide the snackbar. Set the delay you would like to have them appear and hide automatically.

You will probably want to remove the `animateSnackbar` call from the `viewDidAppear` method, as that was put there for the example.

Comment: still doesn't work on my VC, I probably should try it an empty project and work from there. Thank you

Comment: We updated the example, maybe it will help you out: [Snackbar Example](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material/tree/master/Examples/Programmatic/SnackbarController)

Comment: Seems like there is still a problem w/ my snackbar - it doesn't show up, looks like its out of the view or something...

Comment: Well it should be out of the VC until you animate it in with the `visible` state. Can you send a sample project to support@cosmicmind.io, or another reproducible way? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to use snackbar without AppSnackbarController sample usage. Something like Snackbar.animate(snackbar: .visible, delay: 1) would be very handy.

Comment: You can use any component you want that is in a controller, you may need to follow the code in the controller though and transfer it to your own view controller. In general, I am going to offer more components without the need for App*Controllers, and update the older ones to not need controllers as well.

Comment: I still cant seem to use it. I didn't subclass and trying to use it directly  by creating instance of let snackbarController = SnackbarController(rootViewController: self) and then try to animate  snackbarController but nothing showing up.

Comment: Well I am not sure what you have done, you would need to share a project with me.

Comment: @CosmicMind Can I not simply say something like `Snackbar.show("Reminder!!")` in one line instead of doing those heavy configuration? Something like https://cocoapods.org/pods/Toaster